# Handle Entity Framework Code First Migrations in Team Source Control

Tags: c#, git, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm currently working in a team that uses Entity Framework 6.1.3 as main object-relational mapping (ORM) framework.

Most of the time it works really well but the problems start when two or more different team members have added migrations and these should then be merged.

Example from Microsoft:

[image]

In order to keep the `model snapshot` up to date we usually `Add a blank 'merge' migration` to update the snapshot. From PMC:

```
Add-Migration "Fix merge" –IgnoreChanges
```

We could of course `update the model snapshot in the last migration` but since we are using pull requests and validating each others code there can often be two migrations that are pending but none of them are added to the `master` branch yet because they are not reviewed.

Given the blank migration we have however experienced problems here as well. Example: Two migrations have been synced to master and the model snapshot is out of sync. A developer has made some changes to the database models and then does a merge with master. The developer needs to add a blank merge in order for the model snapshot to sync. The problem with using `–IgnoreChanges` is that the migration will be blank even if there are some changes that the developer has done to the models in his branch. If `–IgnoreChanges` is not used then every change from the new migrations will show up as well and probably cause an exception because the code will be added twice.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn481501(v=vs.113).aspx

Is there any other way we could solve this in code? Right now we are alerting migrations in Slack to give them priority in pull requests but it is far from an optimal flow. Given what I have been reading I don't think it is possible but I would gladly be proven wrong. Given the pull request flow we use today updating the model snapshot in the last migration does not always work for us.

Comment: Frankly, this has been asked quite a number of times before. Did none of the previous questions and answers offer a satisfactory solution?

Comment: @GertArnold Yes it has and I think I have read most of the threads. However the solution is always one of the two examples above and I think they both have some drawbacks. If it can be done in another way I would like to know.